# Undefined variable $result (View:/resources/views/frontend/CustomerRequest.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

when i run code then it gives this error: "Undefined variable $result (View:/resources/views/frontend/CustomerRequest.blade.php) ", anyone can plz suggest any solution. Thanks

controller:

```
   public function index()
   {
      $result =  DB:: select('select * from form_request');
      $result= form::all();
      return view('frontend.CustomerRequest')->with('result', $result);
   }
```

view:

```
  @foreach($result as $form)
       
      <tr>
          <td>{{ $form->id }}</td>
          <td>{{ $form->name }}</td>
      </tr>
   @endforeach
```

route:

```
  Route::get('customerrequest',[PostsController::class, 'index']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the syntax `return view('frontend.CustomerRequest')->with('result', $result);` is wrong, that way does not pass the variable to the view page.

Instead it should be `return view('frontend.CustomerRequest', compact('result');`

So change your controller function to this

```
   public function index()
   {
      $result =  DB:: select('select * from form_request');
      $result= form::all();
      return view('frontend.CustomerRequest', compact('result');
   }
```

Now in your view file you should be able to access the `$result` variable.